# Java - A* Search Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, search, a-star

**Issue resolved.**

I've implemented an A* Search algorithm for path-finding in a simple grid-based game. It's my first time doing so, and the implementation works great most of the time. However, sometimes (albeit very rarely) it will get stuck when there is a path available. Of course, the fact that it gets stuck at all makes it not fit for purpose. I assume that I am missing something from my implementation.

I have looked for the issue for several days, to no avail. I have a fast-approaching deadline and a lot of things to do, I'd rather not waste any more time trying to fix this bug.

**Edit:** I've created [a quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJmDzoBZD_s) to demonstrate the issue, that way you can see exactly what's going on. It includes captions.
**Edit:** The `getPath` method:

```
/**
 * @param currentPosition - the vector the avatar currently occupies.
 * @param targetPosition - the vector the avatar is aiming to reach.
 * @param levelMap - a clip map of the level.
 * 
 * @return an {@code ArrayList} of {@link ACTIONS} that the avatar can follow to reach its destination.
 **/
public static ActionPath getPath(Vector2d currentPosition, Vector2d targetPosition, LevelMap levelMap) {
    openTiles = new ArrayList<AStarTile>();
    closedTiles = new ArrayList<AStarTile>();
    targetMet = false;

    AStarTile originTile = AStarTile.fromVector(currentPosition, levelMap.getBlockSize()),
             targetTile = AStarTile.fromVector(targetPosition, levelMap.getBlockSize()),
             currentTile = null,
             parentTile = null;

    ActionPath actionPath = new ActionPath(targetTile);

    if (originTile.equals(targetTile)) {
        targetMet = true;
        return null;
    }

    GVGLogger.logInfo("Creating path from tile " + originTile + " to tile " + targetTile + " (" + currentPosition + " to " + targetPosition + ").");

    /*
     * Start the search.
     */
    openTile(originTile);
    originTile.calculateGeneration();// The origin tile will always be generation 0.
    closeTile(originTile);

    parentTile = originTile;

    while(!targetMet) {
        for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++) {
            currentTile = parentTile.move(i);// Checks an adjacent tile - up, down, left, and right respectively

            if (levelMap.inBounds(currentTile) && levelMap.isAccessible(currentTile) && !isClosed(currentTile)) {
                if (isOpen(currentTile)) {
                    // Check to see if this path to this tile is a better one.
                    currentTile = getOpen(currentTile);

                    if (currentTile.getGeneration() > parentTile.getGeneration() + 1) {
                        // The open version's generation is higher than this version's generation - it's a better path
                        currentTile.setParentTile(parentTile);
                        currentTile.calculateGeneration();
                        currentTile.calculateFinalScore();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    currentTile.setParentTile(parentTile);
                    currentTile.setHeuristic(currentTile.distanceSquared(targetTile));
                    currentTile.calculateGeneration();
                    currentTile.calculateFinalScore();
                    openTile(currentTile);
                }
            }
        }

        if (openTiles.size() > 0) {
            parentTile = getBestOption();
            closeTile(parentTile);

            if (parentTile.equals(targetTile)) {
                targetMet = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            GVGLogger.logWarning("Target unreachable!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Convert the path of tiles into ACTIONS that the avatar can take to reach it.

    for (int i = 0; i != closedTiles.size(); i++) {
        Vector2i difference = getDifference(closedTiles.get(i), (i != closedTiles.size() - 1 ? closedTiles.get(i + 1) : targetTile));

        if (difference.equals(1, 0)) {
            actionPath.add(ACTIONS.ACTION_LEFT);
        }
        else if (difference.equals(-1, 0)) {
            actionPath.add(ACTIONS.ACTION_RIGHT);
        }
        else if (difference.equals(0, -1)) {
            actionPath.add(ACTIONS.ACTION_DOWN);
        }
        else if (difference.equals(0, 1)) {
            actionPath.add(ACTIONS.ACTION_UP);
        }
        else if (difference.equals(0, 0)) {
            return actionPath;
        }
        else {
            GVGLogger.logWarning("Error in path-finding - found a difference of " + difference + "!");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static Vector2i getDifference(AStarTile tileA, AStarTile tileB) {
    return new Vector2i(tileA.getX() - tileB.getX(), tileA.getY() - tileB.getY());
}

public static boolean targetMet() {
    return targetMet;
}

private static void openTile(AStarTile toOpen) {
    if (isClosed(toOpen)) {
        closedTiles.remove(getOpen(toOpen));
    }
    if (!isOpen(toOpen)) {
        openTiles.add(toOpen);
    }
}

private static void closeTile(AStarTile toClose) {
    if (isOpen(toClose)) {
        openTiles.remove(getOpen(toClose));
    }
    if (!isClosed(toClose)) {
        closedTiles.add(toClose);
    }
}

private static boolean isClosed(AStarTile toCheck) {
    return getClosed(toCheck) != null;
}

private static boolean isOpen(AStarTile toCheck) {
    return getOpen(toCheck) != null;
}

/**
 * @return the open tile with the lowest 'final' score.
 **/
private static AStarTile getBestOption() {
    try {
        Collections.sort(openTiles);
        return openTiles.get(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}

private static AStarTile getClosed(AStarTile t) {
    for (AStarTile p : closedTiles) {
        if (p.equals(t)) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static AStarTile getOpen(AStarTile t) {
    for (AStarTile p : openTiles) {
        if (p.equals(t)) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

This method returns a list of 'ACTIONS' that the avatar can take to rich the destination tile. If you wish to see any other methods, please ask.

I wrote this implementation after reading an explanation/tutorial by Patrick Lester found at policyalmanac.org ("A* Pathfinding for Beginners").

I'd really appreciate it if you could glance over my implementation and point out any issues, especially if you are experienced with the A* Search algorithm. I think the code is pretty self-documenting, but please feel free to ask me to elaborate on anything if necessary.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please do not post your code on an external resource. Post the bits that are relevant to the question directly here instead.

Comment: @tnw The code is not working as intended, and therefore it *does not* belong on Code Review.

Comment: Right, lesson learnt. I just figured that would be neater, to avoid filling the question with code.

I also figured I'd be better off adding all of it as opposed to the method in question, in case somebody wished to check other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it - I added a check on the generation when closing a tile. It now backtracks slightly instead of getting stuck.

Solution:

```
    if (!closedTiles.isEmpty() && toClose.getGeneration() != lastClosed().getGeneration() + 1) {
        openTiles.remove(getOpen(toClose));
        return;
    }
```

I'm so glad I've fixed it. Big thanks to anybody who took the time to read and/or answer the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things look suspicious:

### One

```
currentTile.getGeneration() > parentTile.getGeneration() + 1
```

Should this be >= instead of >?

### Two

```
currentTile.setHeuristic(currentTile.distanceSquared(targetTile));
```

Squared distance is not an admissible heuristic as it can over-estimate the distance.  Try using Manhattan distance (or simply setting the heuristic to 0 for a less efficient but more reliable search).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It's > because it it were >=, the alternate path could be the same length, whereas I'm checking for a _better_ path.   Ah, okay, I will see if I can tweak that. Setting the heuristic to 0 completely broke it, however.